# How to randomize search results

Tags: content-search

I am using Sitecore.ContentSearch library (lucene index). How can I randomize search results before getting results? I have more than 10000 items so I do not want to upload all results to memory and after randomize collection. Also it should support paging.

Comment: Is it an option for you to switch to Solr? I don't believe there's a good way to do it with Lucene.

Comment: no, I need to do it with Lucene

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can achieve this via Sitecore ContentSearch API. But Lucene/SOLR does have the ability for dynamic randomised sort fields.

```
 <types>
  ...
  <fieldType name="random" class="solr.RandomSortField" />
  ... 
 </types>
 <fields>
  ...
  <dynamicField name="random*" type="random" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  ...
 </fields>
```

The idea being, you then add `sort=random_your-seed` to the query, and will get search results back in random order. As long as the seed stays the same, your order will be the same (allowing for paging). When you then generate a new search, just generate a new seed key.

References:

- https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_3_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/RandomSortField.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234102/solr-return-random-results-sort-by-random
- http://blog.tremend.com/2007/05/17/a-z-0-9-custom-sorting-in-lucene/

Comment: where I should put this part of config?

Comment: can it be used for lucene?

Answer (score 0):

Building on the answer about `solr.RandomSortField`, Sitecore now provides the random dynamic field automatically, it's ready to use. Here is a [blog post](https://ygangelchuang.wordpress.com/2017/06/28/sitecore-solr-using-random-sort-field/) on the topic for details, but essentially you can just use it like:

```
var random = $"{new Random().Next()}_random";
queryable.OrderBy(result => result[random]);
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't seem to work with SolrCloud. Based on what I'm seeing, I assume each instance has its own random order based on the seed.

Comment: @Marko that may be true but for a single query it should be querying the solr node that is currently the leader for that index.